Facebook Page post successful via Graph API but invisible even for admins
So,I managed to get an API key with the correct permissions to make posts as a Page. Based off of some online reading, other users should not see the posts I make just yet as my Facebook App has not yet gone live. However, according to those texts, I should still be able to see them as I am the admin, but I check the page, and I cannot see any post that I've made through the Graph API. I'm not sure if I'm done something wrong or not. No errors appears, no crashes occur.
Edit: Using a different source text, the new posts appear for some reason. I'm wondering if this has to do with links in the content. Do links within these kinds of posts have to appear under their own parametre(s)?

It seems that what happened was that I needed to insert all my links only into the link parametre in put_object().
